# LibGDX Z index for groups

Tags: libgdx

Have three groups, `A`, `B` and `C`.

Let `B` and `C` be children of `A`.

Now set

```
B.setZIndex(3)
C.setZIndex(2)
```

Why is `C` drawn **over** `B`, if `B` has a greater Z index?

If you do this:

```
C.setZIndex(2)
B.setZIndex(3)
```

It works. However, I want to set `B`'s index before I set `C`'s. So, what's up?

(I know that `C` is drawn over `B` because each group contains an image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

Found it. In the method setZIndex(), this line is the one that moves the children:

```
children.insert(index, this);
```

So the Z index is not a "true" z index which represents the depth, but the index of the children in the parent's children array. So if you try to put a child at position 3 in the array when there are only 2, it will be put at the end. Same when you try to put it at position 2.

If you want a correct ordering, you will then have to put them at positions 0 and 1, no more, no less, or else the results will be counter-intuitive.

**EDIT**: To apply this to your problem, then you put an actor at index 2, libGDX tries to put the actor at position 2 in the array. 2 being too big for the array, it puts it at the end. Same for 3. So that is why it is always the last one to call setZIndex that will be put last, and drawn in front. If you use 0 and 1, like I said, everything will work expectingly.

**EDIT 2**:

**Summary**: It is not a conventional Z-Index, it is the index in the ArrayList. If you try to place B or C in a cell that does not exist, like 2, 3, -1, etc., then the results will not be what you want.

To put it more simply, you have to understand how ArrayLists work. ArrayList are indexed just like arrays, starting at index 0 and incrementing by one each time a value is added. In your case, You have a group A that contains a ArrayList of children containing B and C. B is (probably) the first one in the list, placing it at index 0. C is at index 1.

If you call setZIndex(0) on C, then A will replace index 0 by C and push B at index 1. Simple as that. B will then be drawn on top of C.

But if you call setZIndex(3) on B, A cannot place B at index 3 because it is too far in the list, there is no cell 3. Instead, it places it at the end of the list, at index 1. Then you call setZIndex(2) on C and the same thing happens. A will, in the end, place C at index 1, pushing B at index 0. C will be drawn on top of B.

Source: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.java

**OLD ANSWER**

Simply because Z index is depth. The more depth, the further it is. An instance with less depth will be drawn on top of one with more depth.

EDIT: Look at it like this. Your screen is index 0. Past your screen, behind it, is positive depth. In front of it, it is negative. If you put your hand in front of your screen, it has a smaller depth, but it renders in front.

Comment: Did you read the question? I'm asking why does changing the order of the statements also affects the rendering output. Basically, `B.setZIndex(3); C.setZIndex(2)` is not the same as `C.setZIndex(2); B.setZIndex(3)` - **even though the values are the same**.

Comment: Oh, i see. I will work on that though, or delete this answer if I come up with nothing. This seems like a weird bug from what I can see.

Comment: I did find this in the documentation: "Setting a z-index higher than the number of children will move the child to the front." Since each of your groups has only 1 children (the image), is looks like the last one to be ordered will always be the one on top. Why it does that, I don't know...

Comment: I read your answer and I "get it" but it's really confusing to read. Can you try explaining it more simply? I think your final comment about the API docs really summarizes it.

Comment: I edited, but I am not a good professor by nature, so if something is still not clear, tell me. I try me best to make it simple, but these are notions that are easy to understand for me, this is probably why I can't simplify it enough.

Comment: I see. This is pretty ridiculous. If I had two groups with the same Z index, and at some point I decided to put something between them, I'd have to make a large rearranging mess. Isn't there something more normal?

Comment: @Omega As I can see, no, there isn't an easy, magical way to do this other than inserting at the wanted index.